# How to set shortcut for `M-" ` in emacs config file?

Tags: key-bindings

I need to assign `M-"` as a shortcut to some function. How do I do that?

Doing this gives error

```
 (define-key some-mode-map (kbd 'M-"') 'somefunction)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use doble-quotes for kbd:

```
 (define-key some-mode-map (kbd "M-\"") 'somefunction)
```